# Upload multiple Image/Video file via HTTP with MultipartRequest

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently working on a project where the user will have an option to upload multiple images and or videos along with other data..

The API I'm using will only accept one file at a time, so I need to loop/string my API requests over every file that has been chosen, from the lists they are in..

This is the method I'm using to upload a single file..

```
Future<void> uploadImage(File imageFile, String id) async {
    String url = 'https://********************************';
    var headers = {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $userToken'
    };
    try {
      final mimeTypeData = mime.lookupMimeType(imageFile.path).split('/');
      final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
      final fileToUpload = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'file',
        imageFile.path,
        contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]),
      );
      imageUploadRequest.headers.addAll(headers);
      imageUploadRequest.fields['ext'] =
          '${mimeTypeData[0]}/${mimeTypeData[1]}';
      imageUploadRequest.files.add(fileToUpload);
      final streamedResponse = await imageUploadRequest.send();
      print(streamedResponse.statusCode);
      if (streamedResponse.statusCode != 200) {
        throw Exception(
            'http.patch error: statusCode= ${streamedResponse.statusCode}');
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Suppose I am storing the information about the selected video/images in two separate lists

```
List<ImageFile> images = [];
List<VideoFile> videos = [];
```

How would I go about grabbing the items from those lists and perform a separate API request for each one?

P.S. This API request needs to be triggered by another one that will be sending other data, and only if the lists contain files. I think I can work that bit out but if someone would like to show an example that would be great.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: check `Future.forEach` static method - the docs say: *"Performs an action for each element of the iterable, in turn.

The action may be either synchronous or asynchronous.

Calls action with each element in elements in order. If the call to action returns a Future<T>, the iteration waits until the future is completed before continuing with the next element."*

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the reply.. I've never used this before. How do I target the list/files?

Would it be like this?

if(images.length > 0){Future uploadImages(images, uploadImage).then((response) => print(response));}

Comment: you have `List<ImageFile> images` so pass it (and action that returns `uploadImage()` `Future`) to `Future.forEach` method

Comment: ok great, thanks for your help, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Here is my[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255358/2462531)