# http MultipartRequest file not receiving in server

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to upload image to my server but it's not receiving in my server when I upload file from app. But if I upload via postman it works but not from simulator
My Code

```
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
'POST', Uri.parse(''));
request.fields['title'] = title.text;
request.fields['sub_title'] = subTitle.text;
request.files
.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('profile_photo', photo.path));
request.files

.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('profile_video', video.path));
var response = await request.send();
var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();

print(responseString);
`

Output

{'title': 'zia', 'sub_title' : 'sultan', 'profile_photo' : {}, 'profile_video' : {}}
```

Comment: try using `await File.fromUri("<path/to/file>").readAsBytes()` in place of http.MultipartFile.fromPath, also set a media type see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354916/10409567

Comment: I don't want to send file as bytes if I send like this way I need to change code in server then for app and web I need to write different logic and that's messy

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar issue and here is the solution to how I fixed it:

```
var fileExtension = AppUtils.getFileExtension(filePath);
      if (fileExtension.isEmpty) {
        AppUtils.showToast('File extension was not found');
        return false;
      }
      final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('vid', filePath,
          contentType: MediaType('application', fileExtension));
      request.files.add(file);
      var res = await request.send();

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        final respString = await res.stream.bytesToString();
        debugPrint('respString: $respString');
      }
```

AppUtils:

```
class AppUtils {
  static String getFileExtension(String filePath) {
      try {
        int index = filePath.lastIndexOf('.');
        return filePath.substring(index + 1);
      } catch (e) {
        return '';
      }
  }
}
```